# Codeigniter per page value not sent

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am using codeigniters pagination and it does not seem to be working well for me. Well i click on another index, it gives me a database error because it sends "&per_page=2" into the query as OFFSET. I dont know why this is happening. Please help.

Controller:

```
public function allcars($id = 1)
    {
        $this->load->model('process');
        $this->load->library("pagination");      
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->process->record_count();
        $config["per_page"] = 2;
        $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
        if ($id == 2){
             $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "main/allcars/2";
        }
        else{
             $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "main/allcars/1";
        }
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        if($this->uri->segment(3)){
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
        }
        else{
        $page = 0;
        }
        if ($id == 2){
             $data["results"] = $this->process->allcars_oldest($config["per_page"], $page);
        }
        else{
             $data["results"] = $this->process->allcars_newest($config["per_page"], $page);
        }
         $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        $this->load->view('allcars', $data); 
    }
```

Model:

```
public function record_count() {
        return $this->db->count_all("cars");
    }
    function allcars_newest($limit, $start)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT '.$limit.' OFFSET '.$start);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
    function allcars_oldest($limit, $start)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM cars ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT '.$limit.' OFFSET '.$start);
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

View:

```
<body>
        <div id="menu"><a href="/"><img id="logo" src="../../assets/Picture1.png"></a>
                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) { ?>
            <a href="/main/logout"><button class="btn btn-1 btn-1d">Logout</button></a>
                <button class="btn btn-1 btn-1d">Profile</button>

                <?php }else{ ?>

                <a href="/main/login"><button class="btn btn-1 btn-1d">Login/SignUp</button></a>

                <?php } ?>
                <button class="btn btn-1 btn-1d">FAQ</button>
                <a href='/main/allcars'><button class="btn btn-1 btn-1d">All Cars</button></a>
        </div>
        <div id='main'>
            <h1><?php echo sizeof($query); ?> Result(s) Found</h1>
            <?php
            foreach ($query as $item) 
                { ?>
                <div class='cars'>

                        <?php
                            echo '<img class="car_image" src="' . $item->image_link . '">';
                            ?>
                            <div class='content'>
                                <?php
                                    echo '<p class="title">' . $item->make . ' ' . $item->model . ' ' . $item->year . '</p>';
                                    echo '<p class="price"> ₦'. $item->price.'</p>';
                                    echo '<p class="description">' . $item->description. '</p><br>';
//                                  echo $item->color . '<br>';
                                ?>
                            </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                }?>
                <div id="pagination">
<ul class="tsc_pagination">

<!-- Show pagination links -->
</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which database error you are getting ?

Comment: For debug reasons you should `print_r` the `$config` array before you call `...allcars_newest` / `...oldest`. Also `echo` `$limit` and `$start` in those functions. I doubt this has anything to do with CodeIgniters pagination, but rather some bogus data in the array / variables.

Comment: you should remove "&per_page=" from &per_page=2(any number) using regular expression.(work around solution)